# Flutter get infos about crash on startup

Tags: flutter, crash

We have build an app and it is fine when

- debugging in IntelliJ Idea on a real device
- building an apk in release mode, putting it on a real device

but not when building an appbundle, uploading it on the playstore and downloading the apk (AppBundle -> Downloads -> Signed Universal APK).
Then most times the app does only show the white screen with the icon and sometimes it is starting after a view minutes - but most times not.

The app is not released as google rejects the release because the app is not working.
What is the best way to get infos about the crash in this case?